# how to save images so it doesn't override the image already created

Tags: php

I have the following code that saves an image but when it starts to save the next images it writes over the image that was already created. It does this 10 times and at the end I am left with one image and not 10 seperate images how can i fix this issue?

```
$album_id = $_GET['id'];
$url = 'http://website.com/xml/albums/site/'.$album_id.'/gallery/';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

//album title and url
$album_title = $xml['title'];
$album_url = 'http://website.com'.$xml['html'];

//creates photo album directory
$thisdir = getcwd();
mkdir($thisdir."/".$album_id.' - '.$album_title , 0777);

//obtains all photos and saves them to a directory
foreach($xml as $xml_node) {
    $attributes = $xml_node->attributes();
    $file_url = 'http://website.com'.$attributes['src'];
    $file_name = $attributes['subtitle'];

    //save images
    copy($file_url, $thisdir.'/'.$album_id.' - '.$album_title.'/'.$file_name);

}
```

XML file

```
<photo src="/media/albums/1006969.jpg" title="Red" subtitle="01.jpg" />
<photo src="/media/albums/1006970.jpg" title="Red" subtitle="02.jpg" />
<photo src="/media/albums/100971.jpg" title="Red" subtitle="03.jpg" />
<photo src="/media/albums/1006972.jpg" title="Red" subtitle="04.jpg" />
```

Comment: Make sure the file name is unique on each save.

Comment: What are **actual** attributes? Are the filenames intended to be the same or it's just an accident? What is the actual XML data?

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the file exists, and if it does, change the name.

```
foreach($xml as $xml_node) {
    $attributes = $xml_node->attributes();
    $file_url = 'http://ebsite.com'.$attributes['src'];
    $file_name = $attributes['subtitle'];

    $path = $thisdir.'/'.$album_id.' - '.$album_title.'/'.$file_name;

    $i = 2;
    while(file_exists($path)) {
        $path = $thisdir.'/'.$album_id.' - '.$album_title.'/' . $i . '-' . $file_name;
        ++$i;
    }

    file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($file_url));
}
```

That would make some pretty ugly named files, but hopefully you get the idea.  Just come up with some kind of pattern (like prefixing it with an integer if it exists, starting with 2 and incrementing).  Then, apply that pattern in a loop.

Comment: actually `$file_name` contains the file name and extension. so   the full path would be something like $album_title/1.jpg, $album_title/2.jpg and so on

Comment: Ah, well in that case you'd have to process it a bit.  But once again, hopefully the general idea is conveyed.  Also, whoever down voted me, please explain (assuming it wasn't you for the $file_name thing, which does not warrant a downvote in my opinion :p).  Down voting and running (if someone did) offers nothing useful to anyone involved, and is just frustrating.  (Second time it's happened today...)

Comment: i added the attributes as seen in the xml document

Answer (score 0):

looks to me like you are depending on the `$attributes['subtitle']` being unique. instead, maybe you need to use an actual unique index, such as the position of the XML node within its parent?

Comment: Position of the XML node does not guarantee that in the future the file will not be over written.  He may be redownloading albums later (or something else that could cause a collision in the future).

Comment: @Kae Verens i added the attributes as seen in the xml document

Answer (score 0):

it seems the problem has nothing to do with *saving files* but most likely you are processing your XML wrong way.

first of all do a `print_r($xml);` and see what actual node you have to process to get the filenames.

it is also would be better to print filenames on the screen instead of creating actual files while you are sorting things out.